# Crashes after installing windows update

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I installed Reactive Extensions for .Net3.5 SP1 V1.0.2856.0.  Everything was working fine I build a windows service based on one line of code

```
 Scheduler.NewThread.Schedule(action, new DateTimeOffset(startDate));
```

The thread starts on time however after few moments the application crashes:-

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
   Message="Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.\r\nParameter name: timeout"
   Source="mscorlib"
   ParamName="timeout"
   StackTrace:
        at System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Schedule>b__0()
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException:
```

I uninstall the windows update and used the repair option of the Reactive Extensions installer.  Still nothing work.  I think there is some value in the registry is changed and need to be stored back.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception stack trace suggests your scheduled action is being executed, my guess is that the action you are passing contains a call to `Thread.Sleep` with an incorrect value. Is it negative?

Comment: The problem is I did not write Thread.Sleep.  it is called internally.  There must be some configuration regarding RX is changed during a windows update.  Do you know where to check?

Comment: There is no system level configuration with Rx (certainly no registry settings). I believe the v1.x installer (now depricated) GAC'd assemblies, but that's it. I can't understand why any internal code ever called `Thread.Sleep` though - seems a little odd. However, there were certainly breaking changes between Rx 1.0 and 1.x. You'll need to provide more context if you want an answer.

Comment: Just checked the source code, there's no Thread.Sleep call in the current version; that's not to say it wasn't there in 1.x - but I don't have a copy available to reflect over at the moment.